# Are there hyoid bones of Homo habilis in the fossil record?

Tags: human-evolution

Hyoid bones have been found for *Homo erectus*, *Homo neanderthalensis*, *Australopithecus afarensis*, and some more hominids. Have hyoid bones been found from *Homo habilis*?

---

References:

Capasso, L., E Michetti., & R, D'Anastasio. (2009). A Homo Erectus Hyoid Bone: Possible Implications for the Origin of the Human Capability for Speech. Coll. Antropo. 32(4), 1007–1011

Alemseged, Z., Spoor, F., Kimbel, W. H., Bobe, R., Geraads, D., Reed, D., & Wynn, J. G. (2006). A juvenile early hominin skeleton from Dikika, Ethiopia. Nature, 443(7109), 296-301.

Steele, J., Clegg, M., & Martelli, S. (2013). Comparative morphology of the hominin and african ape hyoid bone, a possible marker of the evolution of speech. Human biology, 85(5), 639-672.